# Learning probability via linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, reference-request

I've heard that much of probability theory can be thought of in terms of linear algebra (e.g. as [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440911/36869) explains). Are there any good books that teach probability through a linear algebra perspective?

For context, I'm finishing up a pure math linear algebra course (and reading Axler's LADR). Afterwards, I'm really interested in using this knowledge to re-learn probability from a linear algebra perspective (especially since my probability course was pretty spotty).

Comment: Linear algebra is a basic knowledge "of the language", which is used almost everywhere. I don't think it is so special for probability.

Comment: That answer does not show that "much of probability theory can be thought of in terms of linear algebra", as far as I can see. It's talking about a few topics that are much more specialized than "much of probability theory".

Comment: I agree with the above two commenters. The answer is referring to multivariate problems in statistics, which hardly encompasses the majority of probability theory. Linear algebra is just a language adequate/suited for any discussion of multi-dimensional (finite-dimensional) phenomena, which really doesn't constitute the bulk of interesting probability theory. If you want to understand probability theory better, what you need to do is learn measure theory.

Comment: This seems to be a fabulous text [Linear Algebra with Probability](http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19/math19b_2011.pdf)